# $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a $\mathbb{R}$ linear function and holomorphic (entire) then $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$ linear function

Tags: complex-analysis

Well, in order to show that $\mathbb{C}$ linearity when $\mathbb{R}$ linearity is given (when $\mathbb{R}$ linearity means $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R} , z,w\in \mathbb{C} : f(az+bw)=af(z)+bf(w) $), all is needed to be shown is that $\forall z\in \mathbb{Z} f(iz) = if(z)$ [becasue for $a=\alpha + i\beta,b=\gamma + i \delta \in\mathbb{C}$ $f(az+bw) = f(\alpha z + \gamma w + i(\beta z+\delta w)) =_{c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{C}} f(c_1+ic_2) = f(i\cdot(-ic_1 +c_2)) = f(iz)$].

Yet I don't succeed to use the fact the $f$ is entire to prove $f(iz)=if(z)$ , I tried to use Cuachy-Riemann for $g(z) =f(iz)$ which is also holomorphic due to the fact that $f$ is entire. Also I wish not to use the equivalence between holomorphic and analytic, when observing $f(iz) = \sum_0^\infty c_i(iz)^j = \sum_0^\infty c_j \cdot i^j \cdot z^j$ I don't see how to demonstrate that this is equal to $i\sum_0^\infty c_jz^j$.

Comment: Hint: use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Are we talking about functions $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$? If so, you could use the basic linear algebra fact that any $\mathbb{R}$-linear function is of the form $f(z) = az+b\bar{z}$.

Comment: @Wojowu , I tried (mentioned), all I know is that when $f(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then $u_x(x,y) = v_y(x,y) , u_y(x,y) = -v_x(x,y)$, so I tried to apply it for $f(i(x+iy)) =f(-y+ix)$, but couldn't find out how to use this result. If you may give another hint for how to use the Cauchy Riemann equations to solve the problem I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $z \in \Bbb C$
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)  &= f\bigl(\operatorname{Re}(z) \cdot 1 +  \operatorname{Im}(z) \cdot i \bigr)\\
 &= \operatorname{Re}(z) \cdot f(1) + \operatorname{Im}(z) \cdot f(i) \\
 &= \frac{z + \bar z}{2}\cdot f(1) +  \frac{z - \bar z}{2i} \cdot f(1i) \\
 &= \frac{f(1)-if(i)}{2} \cdot z + \frac{f(1)+if(i)}{2} \cdot \bar z \\
 &= A z + B \bar z
\end{align}
$$
with some constants $A, B \in \Bbb C$.

It remains to show that $f(z) = A z + B \bar z$ is holomorphic if and only if $B=0$, and there are different ways to do so:

- Write $f(z) = A(x+iy) + B(x-iy)$ and apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations.
- Or: Use the Cauchy-Riemann equation [in the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Independence_of_the_complex_conjugate)
  $$
   0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} (z) = B \, .
  $$
- Or: If $B \ne 0$ then
  $$
   z \mapsto \bar z = \frac{f(z)-Az}{B}
  $$
  would be holomorphic. Again the Cauchy-Riemann equations show that this is not the case.